# An example of a random variable whose both marginal distributions and itself has the same probability distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions

To ask what I want to, let me start with an example:

Let $\chi(x)$ and $\eta(t)$ be two independent random variables. Then we can define a new random variables such as
$$\epsilon_1(x,t) = \chi(x) + \eta(t),$$
or
$$\epsilon_2(x,t) = \chi(x) \eta(t).$$

Now, it is clear that, even if the underlying probability distributions of $\chi$ and $\eta$ are the same, $\epsilon$ (probably) will have a different probability distribution.

---

Now, the real question:

Let $\epsilon = \epsilon(x,t)$ be a random variable of two variables. Is there any example of a random variable whose both marginal distributions (i.e the probability distribution along a single dimension) and itself has the same probability distribution ?

**Edit:**

The interpretation that @whuber put it in the comments is correct, and I'm looking for non-trivial cases (i.e for example not $\epsilon (x,y) = x$).

Comment: Your terminology doesn't quite conform with convention: when we write of "marginal distributions," that implies the random variable in question is *multivariate.*  Here, $\epsilon$ seems to be a *function* of two variables and you are asking whether there exists a multivariate random variable $(\chi,\eta)$ and a function $\epsilon:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ for which the distributions of $\chi,\eta,$ and $\epsilon$ are the same.  Is this a correct interpretation?  If so, consider the case of iid standard Normal variables and the function $\epsilon(x,y)=(x+y)/\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: There are many other answers you might find uninteresting, too, such as $\epsilon(x,y)=x.$  In light of this, would it be possible to edit your question to (a) clarify it and (b) assure it's not trivial?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment; yes that is the correct interpretation, and  I was looking for non-trivial cases.

Comment: @whuber can you explain why is the dist. of $x,y$ and $\epsilon = (x+y)/\sqrt{2}$ are the same ?

Comment: Normal distributions are determined by their first two moments.  Basic properties of expectation and variance show that $\epsilon$ has a mean of $0$ and variance of $1,$ whence it must have a standard Normal distribution.

Comment: What if they are not normal ? Is there a general form for $\epsilon$ that can work for any distributions

Comment: There are myriad solutions.  For instance, when the common distribution $F$ is continuous, apply the probability integral transform of $\chi+\eta$ to produce a solution: specifically, let $G$ be the distribution function of $\chi+\eta$ define $\epsilon=F^{-1}(G(\chi+\eta)).$ To see that the space of solutions is huge, note that there are very great number of functions $h:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ that preserve the uniform probability and consider $F^{-1}(h(G(\chi+\eta))).$

Comment: @whuber Can you give an example when $F$ is not a uniform distribution ?

Comment: As I stated, this procedure works for literally any continuous distribution.

Comment: @whuber Ok, I believe you, but can you give an example ?

Comment: I gave you a lifetime's worth of examples: pick [any continuous distribution you like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Continuous_distributions) and do the calculation.

Comment: @whuber sure ...